# Is rolling a dice a Gauss distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, dice

I'm in an argument with a friend over rolling a dice several times, for example rolling 5 times. His argument is, that is far more difficult to roll out 1-1-1-1-1 than any other combination (for example 1-5-2-4-3) as the results of the rolls distribute in a Gauss manner so the edges are somehow less probable. His arguments have to do with Bayes theory.
My intuition tells just the opposite since the dices have no memmory and one roll isn't conditioned by the latter, so any combination is equally probable.
I know that dices are a very recurrent topic here but I haven't found an straight answer to my question...

In the final terms it seems is a discussion of the Bayessian against frequentist approaches to probabilistics. We're not going to solve it today... I abandon you since we have a duel at twelve o'clock in the church yard.

**EDIT**
*As I'm seeing many comments and answers here I would like to point out that the discussion is about combinations WITHOUT PERMUTATIONS, that is 12345 is different of 54321.
Furthermore, I said 5 rolls to put a concrete example, but what we were discussing was for a large number of rolls (take large as the number you want...)*

Comment: All combinations are equally probable if the dice is fair and the trials are independent. The probability that we will obtain a certain combination is equal to $(1/6)^5$.

Comment: This is related to the Gambler's fallacy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy

Comment: But the probability to get {1,5,2,4,3} in any order is much larger than the probability to get {1,1,1,1,1}. Maybe you can compute their ratio?

Comment: Is rolling 1-5-2-4-3 same as 1-2-3-4-5?

Comment: Yes, is the same, order doesn't matter

Comment: Is the duel with sabres or blunderbuses?

Comment: If the probability of an event happening is seriously small compared to other events (here the probability of having only ones, compared to say having {1,5,4,2,3} is relatively smaller), we can NOT conclude that Gaussian behavior is present.

Comment: And anyway I fail to see any gaussianity in rolling 5 times a 6-sided dice.

Comment: I updated my answer to include part of your edit, see the section "Update".

Comment: Oh, blunderbuses of course, that of sabres is quite old fashioned...

Comment: "dice" is plural. "die" is singular.

Comment: In my last comment (11/10/2015) I tried to clarify the original question, but I have not received an answer yet. Are you still interested in the question?

Comment: Carlos, I'm sorry if my language is not enough mathematical for you, but as I told you in my last comment on your answer theres a misconception in the way you interpret the question, maybe because I don't expose correctly or maybe because you read it differently.... Either way I'm not sure it's the correct answer, and I understand that you want it as the accepted answer after a so elaborated exposition, but I cannot accept it, at least for the moment.

Comment: I won't insist more in trying to understand what you really want. I just want to add that the Gaussian approximation, as is described in my answer, does nothing to do with Baye's theorem, it's just a consequence of the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). I don't see how this would be a "discussion of the Bayessian against frequentist approaches" of probability. The [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations#Axiomatic_probability) of probability does not change the axiomatic base used to answer your question.

Comment: Who won the duel, any updates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that since dice events are independent and each die is a fair die (no side is more likely than the other), rolling one die multiple times is equivalent to rolling multiple dice all at once.

So, whether rolling a die $n$ times, or $n$ dice at once, each permutation is as likely as the next. For five six-sided dice there are $6^5$ possible outcomes. Of those $7776$ possibilities only one is five 1's. That is roughly a 0.0129% chance of rolling five 1's.

Any other sequence has the same probability. Five 2's, five 3's, five 4's, five 5's, all 6's, 1-2-3-4-5-6, 6-5-4-3-2-1, 1-3-2-4-5-6, 1-4-2-3-5-6, etc. all have a 0.0129% chance.

But if only the combination matters (any order -- like a poker hand) and not the permutation (a specific order -- like a combination lock) you should see why $n$ of any kind is so much rarer. There are multiple ways to roll some combinations.

That is why the odds in Craps are distributed the way they are. Sevens are the most common dice combination. Snake eyes and boxcars are the least common.

Rolling dice is a discrete distribution, while the normal distribution, AKA the Gaussian distribution, is continuous by definition. The distribution is technically binomial, which [approximates the normal distribution as n gets large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764816/how-to-create-a-discrete-normal-distribution-in-r).

So while your friend is right that dice COMBINATION probabilities approximate the Gaussian distribution, you are also correct that each PERMUTATION of dice are equally as likely. It is hard to think of a real life example where dice permutations are used. If anyone knows of any I would be interested to learn about them.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right, is far more difficult to roll out $11111$ than any other sequence. Let's see why.

**Formalism**

Let $X$ be number of times a $1$ appears in $5$ independent rolls of a die. Then, $X \sim \text{Binom}(5, \frac{1}{6})$, and

$$\text{Prob. of sequence 11111} = P(X=5) = \left(\frac{1}{6} \right)^5$$

$$\text{Prob. of any other sequence} = 1-P(X=5) = 1-\left(\frac{1}{6} \right)^5$$

**Intuition**

Any other combination different than $11111$ is more probable because in general that any other combination has more options per roll. Even in the more restrictive case of any other combination where a $1$ does not appear, you would have $5$ possibilities ($2$ to $6$) per roll that would make that event occur. In turn, the sequence $11111$ only has one possibility per roll ($1$).

**The Gaussian approximation**

If you define a random variable $X$ as above over the experiment of successive and independent rolls of a die, then that [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) random variable with parameters $n$ (number of rolls) and $p$ (probability of a success) can be approximated through a Gaussian distribution with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$ *when $n$ is large and $p$ is not too close to neither $1$ or $0$*. Do the values of $n$ and $p$ in your problem satisfy that requirement? Let's see how the binomial PMF looks like for those values:

$\hspace{2.5cm}$[image]

Not so good, right? You can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) some rules of thumb to decide when the normal approximation could be good and [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/NormalApprox.pdf) a proof about the Gaussian approximation of the binomial distribution.

If in the description of the problem, you make $n$ as large as you want, then, with $p=\frac{1}{6}$, the Gaussian approximation is good. Let's see:

$\hspace{2.5cm}$[image]

---

**About why this approach works only when $12345$ is different than $54321$**

Let's see now why the definition of $X$ as above indeed works only when we consider that $12345$ is different of $54321$. To do that, let's consider a toy example. Suppose you roll three times a $2$-sided die and let $X$ be the number of times a $1$ appears. So, for example, $X=2$ when any of the following sequences occur

$$121\quad 112\quad 211$$

In this way $P(X = 2) = 3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$, but let's write this in a more interesting way

$$P(X = 2) = \binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

...and what is this? Nothing more that a binomial probability! In this way, we can see that using binomial probabilities, we are considering that $121$, $211$ and $112$ are all **different sequences** but with the **same probability**! and that's why we multiply the probability term $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ by $\displaystyle \binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: Notably, with $p$ so small as $10^{-3}$, even with $n$ as large as $10^5$, the CDF of the rescaled binomial deviates from the normal by more than 0.025.

Comment: @Ian: I messed up the Gaussian approximation with the Poisson approximation, sorry about that, I changed the parameters to give a better example, where $n$ is large but $p$ is not too close to neither 0 or 1.

Comment: These are these "fine prints" (n large, p not too close to 0 or 1) that would be the most useful pieces of information to include in your answer. As written, you seem to encourage the reader to think that indeed the gaussian approximation is useful/good/natural in the setting of the question (n=5...).

Comment: @Did I added that information, thanks for the comment.

Comment: How do you spect I accept your answer if you say my friend is right and not me?   ;-)

Comment: Sorry @Carlos Mendoza, I never wanted to offend you... In fact your answer is very elaborated (and my friend is very happy with it) althought you took the word "combinations" too literaly... As I specify in the later EDIT the discussion was about combinations without permutations, but thanks anyway, I appreciate your answer. Best regards

Comment: @Vi100 I added an additional note explaining why in the approach I used the order of the numbers matters.

Comment: Carlos, you keep having a misconception about my question... I think is quite obvious it means that is more difficult to roll five consecutive 1s than rolling another combination (without permutations). This doesn't mean ALL other combinations, that of course would be more probable by simple aggregation. The question is one sequence compared with another, not with all other... Sorry if it wasn't clear, spoken language is not as accurate as mathematical, and also english isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: @Vi100 I don't get it. If your question was "one sequence compared with another, not with all other", then pick that another sequence and make a new edit to your question. Don't you want to pick it? Should be any other sequence? Then I am answering your question. By other hand, "[combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) without [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)" is a misnomer, the correct expression would be [permutations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition).

Comment: But `1-P(X=5)` is the total probability of all other sequences. i.e. the probability of not rolling 11111. OP was comparing the probability of two sets. Not one set versus the rest. Since they are independent events you have 1/6 chance to roll a one * 1/6 chance to roll a one again. 1/36 to roll snake eyes. If order matters, you have a 1/6 chance to roll a one * 1/6 chance to roll a two. Again 1/36 chance to roll a one followed by a two. If order doesn't matter, you have a 1/6 chance to roll a one * 1/6 chance to roll a two + 1/6 chance to start with a two * 1/6 chance to roll a one. 1/18.

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i\right)^5$$

We can expand this with the [Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). The coefficients before each monomial is the number of configurations to get the occurrences of the corresponding exponents. For example, the term $x_1^2x_2^2x_3$ will tell us that there are as many combinations of 2 ones, 2 twos and one three as the coefficient before it.

For the general case this coefficient will be $$\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^n e_i!}$$ where $e_i$ are the exponents, i.e. the individual occurrences.

In the extreme case if all exponents are one it becomes all possible permutations: $n!$ which is $5! = 120$ configurations.

And if one exponent is n and all other 0:

$$\frac{n!}{n!0!0!\cdots} = \frac{n!}{n!} = 1$$